# JSON issue seems like it should work

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Says I have an unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Any idea what is wrong? Probably simple but i'm still learning.

```
> 29 |   .then(response => response.json())
  30 |   .then(user => {
  31 |     if (user.id) {
  32 |       this.props.loadUser(user)
         this.props.onRouteChange('home');
        }
       })
      }
```

Comment: response is coming as undefined or null . that the reason  .json is breaking

Comment: Your response is a html page, not json.

Comment: log you response and see if you are getting anything or not

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this when the server returned errors. For example, instead of returning a json, it would return some html markup:

`<!doctype html>`

That unexpected symbol is probably the opening bracket of the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

The response is not a JSON response and is most likely an HTML error page witha 400 or 500 error code range.

It seems you are using fetch so you could change that function to say

```
.then(response => response.ok && response.json())
```

That will check if it's a good result before assuming that it's JSON, but you should probably add a `.catch()` to catch these times that it's not a response that you expected.

You can most likely look in the network tab to see the error, or in your catch do something like this:

```
.catch(response => response.text().then(errText => console.log(errText))
```